# Goolge maps Api returns different result via code vs browser

Tags: java, google-maps

Calling the same URL returns different location coordinates:
[image]

URL: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=apicode&query=1412%20norway

Code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=apicode&query=1412%20norway");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

    //using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    //{
    //    string json = "{\"longUrl\":\"http://www.google.com/\"}";
    //    System.Console.WriteLine(json);
    //    streamWriter.Write(json);
    //}

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        System.Console.WriteLine(responseText);
    }
}
```

Thanks

**update**

Comparison of two requests in fiddler. Why do i get different results?
[image]

Comment: When I make a request to the URL you linked in your question, I get [these results](https://screenshot.googleplex.com/Z2NNvm613Pp.png) which are different to your web service request results.

Comment: I couldn't access the link, check it please. Yes the problem is why i get different results of same url when called in code VS browser. I updated the issue with comparison of requests in fiddler.

Comment: Sorry about the link not working. Try [this one](https://ibb.co/kGbgVH). I think you should submit a bug report on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Can you intercept the actual request that sends Java code? Try to figure out if HttpWebRequest URL-encodes your search string one more time. You are passing the URL-encoded value `1412%20norway`, what happens if you send '1412 norway' instead? or '1412+norway'?

Comment: Tried with '1412 norway' and '1412+norway'  bu i still get wrong location

Comment: I have the same problem with this request in php
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?key=APIKEY&address=Portugal,AMOR

Comment: turns out the problem was with the missing quotes in `address="Portugal,AMOR"`
Added this quotes and problem solved.

Comment: Try `query='1412+norway'`